# Is it possible to transfer Shinigami powers accidentally?

Tags: bleach

In Bleach, Rukia transfers her Shinigami powers to Ichigo by having him stab himself in the chest with her zanpakuto.

If a person is stabbed in the chest by a zanpakuto, can they absorb half of the Shinigami's powers, or does it have to be intentional? If it does have to be intention, is there any reason given for that?

Comment: I think I remember that the reason why Ichigo took all of Rukia's powers was explained somewhere in the manga... but I totally can't remember in what part of the manga was it =(

Comment: Maybe Ichigo like a power sponge...

Comment: To clarify my question because everyone who answers isn't answering the question asked, I want to know if it is possible to transfer Shinigami powers accidentally, NOT why Ichigo absorbed more of Rukia's powers than he was supposed to.

Comment: @kuwaly I have answered that too. Unfortunately the way I interpreted your question, it felt like you were asking both. May I suggest you edit out the "transfer more than half" part from your question, and maybe move it to a new question?

Comment: @Deidara-senpai I edited out that part, and I just read that part in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transfer of powers has to be intentional because otherwise the shinigami won't be able to stab anybody without losing their powers. Ichigo was stabbed by Kenpachi later in the Soul Society arc, and that did not give him the latter's powers.

Answer (score 1):

The transfer was initiated by Rukia, but since Ichigo has such a powerful and dominant reiatsu (spiritual power), he ended up taking all of her death god powers.

It normally shouldn't happen, but Ichigo is a bit of a special case.

Answer (score 1):

> Rukia stated that she didn't intend to transfer all her powers to Ichigo, meaning that it may be possible for shinigami powers to transfer accidentally.

However, Ichigo is a special case.

> Ichigo was born with high spiritual energy considering his parents weren't regular humans, his father being a soul reaper and his mother being a Quincy.
>  Due to Ichigo's high spiritual energy, all of Rukia's shinigami powers transferred to Ichigo.

Assuming this is only because Ichigo is a special case, it may be possible for shinigami powers to accidentally transfer, but not all of it. 
This is my theory on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that Rukia's powers were transferred is fundamentally wrong. Since Ichigo was a vessel capable of storing large Reiatsu (soul force), when she forcefully transferred her Reiatsu, Ichigo ended up pulling all of it. Hence rendering her powerless. She just poured her Reiatsu into him. Not her powers.

Answer (score -1):

Ichigo is a special case. I do not want to spoil the story, so, I recommend not to read anything below this line

> There is a reason why the shinigami power were transferred to him. You see, he does not have ordinary parents. one of his parents is a former shinigami which caused him to have the capability of transferring shinigami powers to him. He was the only male in the family, and probably being the male he had a different gene than his sisters. makes sense ha?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree...You had me going at the parents thing, but lost me after that.

Comment: I've formatted the answer for you, please include spoilers in the appropriate format. Also, names and terms shouldn't be in code tags.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I will, I did not know they exist. Thanks for the invite to this site. and the edit.

Comment: Glad to have you aboard! If have any questions regarding this site's policies, consult the meta, the faq, or is on chat. Good luck!  :-)

Comment: @Makoto I think he meant that Ichigo being the son of a shinigami makes his genes/DNA "compatible" with the shinigami powers, although the boy/girl thing did not make sense to me either. @ shnisaka If this is what you meant, please edit to make your point clear.